# I want to trigger gitlab-ci pipeline, whenever there is an object put in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci

I am looking for a way to trigger my gitlab ci pipeline whenever there is a object (with specific name) is added in S3 bucket.

I am new with AWS lambda, can someone please help

Comment: You'll want to look at triggering a Lambda from an S3 event.  Then you need to trigger Gitlab.  Examples [like this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) show you how to setup the S3 side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [s3 event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) and deliver these events to other AWS services, including AWS Lambda or SQS queues.

Leveraging these event notifications, you could send the event directly to a lambda function that subscribes to putobject events and parses the [event content structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html) to determine if an object of the specific name was created and use the [create pipeline API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline) to trigger pipelines on GitLab.

Architecture overview:

[image: Architecture overview]